# How to solve glmmTMB object not found error?

Tags: r, glmmtmb

It seems a bit silly to post this as a question, but I haven't been able to find an answer for this.
I want to use the `glmmTMB` package for modelling data with zero-inflation, but when I try to fit the model I want, the function `glmmTMB()` returns the following error:

```r
Error in glmmTMB(y ~ x + (1 | z), data = df, ziformula = x) : object 'x' not found
```

This only happens after I introduce the term for `ziformula`. The model without that term works just fine. For some reason, it seems that the `ziformula` overrides the `data` command in the function.

My glmmTMB package version is 1.1.3 and my R version is 4.1.1.

Here's a little sample data to reproduce the problem:

```
df <- data.frame(y=c(2,2,5,7,3,8,3,2,4,6),
                    x = c(23,21.7,22.5,18,20,19.9,21,20.3,20,20.5),
                    z = c(rep("a",5),rep("b",5)))
glmmTMB(y ~ x + (1|z), data = df, ziformula = x)
```

If anyone has had any similar issue, I would be grateful for any tips on how to solve it!

Comment: Have you tried `ziformula = df$x`?

Comment: @SamR, I have but that gives the following error `Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : invalid model formula in ExtractVars`

Comment: `ziformula` should be a formula with a tilde `~`. See the documentation.

Comment: @Vincent that did the trick, thank you so much! For some reason I missed that while reading on the topic.